# como puedo buscar varios datos guardados en un txt con c#

Tags: c#

tengo este código el funciona si y solo si haga una sola búsqueda

```
        string rutaArchivo = ruta; en esta variable va la ruta de  archivo
        string valorBusqueda = "Palabra"; aquí la palabra que necesito que busque
        List<string> nuevosRegistros = new List<string>();

        foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(rutaArchivo, Encoding.Default))
        {
            if (item.Contains(valorBusqueda))
            {
                nuevosRegistros.Add(item);
            }
        }

        foreach (string item in nuevosRegistros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

pero cuando quiero buscar mas de 1 palabra al mismo tiempo no me muestra ningún dato el programa es tipo consola y no debo de escribir nada por la consola las palabras que se quieran buscar debe estar escritas dentro del código antes de ejecutar

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con más de una palabra? ¿Quieres añadir las líneas que contengan una de las palabras o todas?

Comment: Tienes que poner las palabras que quieres buscar en una lista y poner otro bucle para recorrerlas y mirar si existen en las líneas del archivo, ya que de la manera que lo tienes hecho solo estás mirando si existe 1 palabra

Comment: string[] valorBusqueda = { "PLANTA","GENERACION"}; es algo asi lo que quiero que busque eso esta en filas diferentes lo que quiero es que cuando encuentre esas palabras me traiga todos los datos que hay

Comment: List<string> nuevosRegistros = new List<string>();
            string rutaArchivo = Ruta; 
            string[] valorBusqueda = { "PLANTA","PCH GENERACION"};
            for(int i=0; i > valorBusqueda.LongLength; i++) { 
            foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(rutaArchivo, Encoding.Default))
            {
                if (item.Contains(valorBusqueda[i]))
                {
                    nuevosRegistros.Add(item);                    
                } }            
            foreach (string item in nuevosRegistros)
            { Console.WriteLine(item); } } }

Comment: lo tengo ya así el código lo he probado pero  de a partir el item del foreach no me guarda los registros

Comment: ya me funciono había puesto el signo del for al revés gracias pana

Comment: @jhohanandres Debes responder tu pregunta en el área de abajo con tu explicación y darla por finalizada para su correcto cierre.

Answer (score 2):

Visto los comentarios, me imagino que la solución vino con un código parecido al siguiente:

```
string rutaArchivo = ruta;
        List<string> valoresBusqueda = new List<string> { "Palabra1", "Palabra2" };
        List<string> nuevosRegistros = new List<string>();

        foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(rutaArchivo, Encoding.Default))
        {
            for (int i=0;i< valoresBusqueda.Count; i++)
            {
                if (item.Contains(valoresBusqueda[i]))
                {
                    nuevosRegistros.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string item in nuevosRegistros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```